# Seifert fiber space with homotopically trivial generic fiber

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, seifert-fiber-spaces

Let $X$ be a Seifert fiber space, that is, a 3-manifold which is a circle bundle over a 2-orbifold. Suppose all generic fiber of $X$ is homotopically trivial, can we prove that the universal cover of $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$?

Comment: I think that lens spaces have Seifert fibrations with this property. They fiber over a football orbifold with two cone points of order $n$, where $n$ is the order of the fundamental group. The generic fiber covers the exceptional fibers $n:1$, and hence lifts to the universal cover $S^3$, so is contractible.

Comment: @IanAgol Sorry, I forget to mention the universal cover of $X$ in the question.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from your [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/382277/1446).

Comment: @SteveD: Of course, it does...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this follows from classification of Seifert fibered spaces.  In fact, you can change the hypothesis to "the fiber is torsion in $\pi_1(X)$" and still get the result. $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$

Suppose that $X$ is reducible.  Thus $X$ has $S^2 \times \RR$ geometry and the fiber is not torsion.

Suppose that $X$ has boundary.  The boundary components are tori.  By "one-half lives, one-half dies" there is a unique slope $\gamma$ that dies in homology.  If the fiber is torsion, a power dies in homology, so in fact $\gamma$ is the fiber slope.  The disk theorem tells us that $\gamma$ bounds a disk.  Irreducibility tells us that $X$ is a solid torus.  We appeal to the classification of fiberings of the solid torus and find that the fiber is not torsion, a contradiction.

Suppose that $X$ is algebraically toroidal.  If the immersed torus is a union of fibers then the fibers are not torsion.  If the torus is transverse to the fibers then it is embedded.  In this case $X$ has $\mathbb{E}^3$ geometry, and the fibers are not torsion.

So, $X$ is Seifert fibered, closed, irreducible, and (algebraically) atoroidal.  Thus it has $S^3$ geometry.